# What's the difference between a DataMart and a Fact Table?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, data-warehouse, fact-table

I actually don't understand the exact meaning of DataMart.
For instance , if my datawarehouse has 4 fact tables , does that necessarily mean I have 4 datamarts?

These are the HR fact tables I have.

Fact_Employee_Entrance_Exits
Fact_Employee_Leaves
Fact_Employee_Reviews
Fact_Employee_Compensation

For me , I think that the first three facts would be a datamart that could be used by the
HR department while the last fact table could be used by the Financial Department.

Comment: The term datamart has no agreed definition but very loosely it is group of tables that can be used to answer questions about a particular business/process area. You would expect it to include at least one fact table and its associated dimension tables but any other restriction/definition is probably down to however you want to define datamarts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Data Mart is a subset of a data warehouse that is focused on a specific subject area or department within an organization. It contains a collection of fact tables, dimension tables, and other relevant data that is specifically tailored to meet the reporting and analysis needs of a particular business unit or user group.

In your case, if you have four fact tables in your data warehouse related to HR, namely Fact_Employee_Entrance_Exits, Fact_Employee_Leaves, Fact_Employee_Reviews, and Fact_Employee_Compensation, you can indeed consider creating separate Data Marts for different departments.

Based on your description, it makes sense to have one Data Mart focused on HR, which would include the first three fact tables (Fact_Employee_Entrance_Exits, Fact_Employee_Leaves, Fact_Employee_Reviews). This HR Data Mart would serve as a dedicated reporting and analysis environment for the HR department, providing them with the necessary information about employee entrance and exits, leaves, and reviews.

Similarly, the Fact_Employee_Compensation fact table can be part of a separate Data Mart that caters specifically to the Financial Department. This Financial Data Mart would contain the necessary dimensions and other relevant data required for financial analysis and reporting related to employee compensation.

By creating separate Data Marts, you can provide more focused and tailored data sets to different user groups or departments, enabling them to perform their analysis and reporting more efficiently. It also helps in controlling data access and ensuring that each department gets the data relevant to their specific needs.

Comment: Copy-paste from ChatGPT